# avr-gcc: suppress warning "'__progmem__' attribute ignored"

Tags: avr-gcc

does anybody know how this warning can be suppressed?
there is no way for me to avoid them (they stem from a framework i use).

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you've placed `__attribute__((...))` at a correct position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the gcc(1) man page:

> **-Wno-attributes**
>
> Do not warn if an unexpected "__attribute__" is used, such as unrecognized attributes, function attributes applied to variables, etc.  This will not stop errors for incorrect use of supported attributes.

Answer (score 1):

just add `static` to your declaration

```
PROGMEM static char my_byte[100] = {0x00,0x01,0x02,0x03 ...... }
```

then retrieve it as

```
char any_byte;
int index;
any_byte = pgm_read_byte(&(my_byte[index])) ;
```

Comment: Variables must be declared "const" to be put in program memory space.